# In PBS, how to specify nodes NOT to use

Tags: pbs

when you submit jobs to a PBS server, is it possible to specify the nodes that we do NOT want to use?

Thanks

Comment: what scheduler are you using?

Comment: You can do that with Grid Engine `qsub -h='!host1|!host2'` to avoid `host1` and `host2.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `excludenodes` to exclude two specific hosts, e.g.

```
#PBS -l excludenodes=host1:host2
```